# 'Average' vs 'Mean' - what's more scientifically accepted?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, science

I'm working on a translation of a paper in portuguese to english. In this paper I work with the average of parameter, but I'm not sure if I should use the word 'average' or 'mean' (specially on graphics). For a non native it's the same thing, but I do not know what word is more scientifically accepted.

Comment: "Mean" (in mathematical sense) has a reasonably narrow definition.  "Average" may be more broadly interpreted.  (But of course you need to consider context --  there's an enormous difference between "average American" and "mean American".)  (... Well, maybe not THAT enormous.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you're talking about the median, 'mean' is incorrect.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Now you're just being average.

Comment: @Hot Licks I'm a modal citizen.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Just don't cross over the median.

Answer (score 3):

Technically speaking, *average* is colloquial (i.e. which average do you mean? See [this Wikipedia page on different averages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average#Arithmetic_mean)).

To describe the average of a sample, use: [**sample mean**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SampleMean.html) or [**sample average**](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22sample+average%22&btnG=). Of those, sample mean is [more common in academia](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22sample+mean%22&btnG=), but both are perfectly accepted.

To refer to what is normally referred to as average (i.e. *the sum of n terms divided by n*) use: [**Arithmetic mean.**](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22Arithmetic+mean%22&btnG=)